# Marginal Cost confusion, possible error in book.

Tags: calculus, economics

I'm going through Morris Kline's "Calculus, an Intuitive and Physical Approach".

One of the problems is about Maginal Cost, and it states (page 126, ex 11): *If the cost C of producing $x$ units of an article is $50+3x+2x^2$, what is the MC when $x=50$? What is the cost of producing the $51^{st}$ unit?*

Just taking the derivative of our C function, we get $C'= 4x+3$, which gives us $C'(50)=203$.

Now in order to get the price of the $51^{st}$ unit, I subtract $C(50)$ from $C(51)$, and I get $5405-5200=205$, so the price of the $51^{st}$ unit is not exactly given to us by the rate of change at $x=50$, which intuitively makes sense to me since our $C$ function is not linear and we're considering discrete intervals (units).

However, in the book solutions it is clearly stated **"When $x=50$, $\frac{dC}{dx}=203$. This is the cost of producing the $51^{st}$ unit."**

It seems clear to me that "This" refers to 203. There is no mention anywhere of the number 205.

So I'm confused. Is this an error in the text, and if not, where did I go wrong? Why is my intuition not correct and how is the rate of change over a discrete interval giving us the exact value of a continuous function at a point outside of that interval?

Comment: dC/dx is how much the cost function changes by adding an additional unit, so if the first 50 units cost 5200 dollars then one more will cost ~$203 dollars. Or the 51st unit costs ~$203. Now as you said, there is some discrepancy between discrete cases and continuous functions. While the derivative is not exact, it is approximately the same ( in this case <1%) and so the derivative is often used to express the cost of the next unit even if it isn't perfect.

Comment: @Mark Could you please clarify, I'm still confused because on the one hand you say that the cost of the $51^{st}$ unit is exactly 203 dollars, but on the other hand you seem to confirm that the derivative gives us an approximation, which would imply that 203 is in fact not the exact price.
So what is 205? Is it just not the right way to compute the actual exact price of the $51^{st}$ unit?